# Oracle Database Listener Issue on Windows Server with Public IP

Tags: oracle, tns

I am quite a beginner in this subject, so any suggestions and corrections are welcome!
I set up an Oracle database (21c) on a home-made server, a pc with CentOS 7, and I managed configure everything, including the listener, so it can be accessed locally (anyone conected to the local network). Now I wanted to replicate this on a server we have purchased, which runs Windows Server and has a public IP, so that the database can be accessed globally.
I assumed that the steps would be similar, but it seems they are not. The listener "starts" without generating errors, but it shows status as "unknown" instead of "ready". When I try to connect (easy connect, user/pwd@ip:port/sid_name) it doesn't work. I'm sharing the configuration files as I have them:
listener.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle21c)
      (SID_NAME = irm2)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\Oracle21c\bin\oraclr.dll")
      (SID_NAME = irm2)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\Oracle21c)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = *nombre_de_pc*)(PORT = 1522))
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\user

SAVE_CONFIG_ON_STOP_LISTENER = TRUE
```

tnsnames.ora:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\user\homes\OraDB21Home1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

IRM2 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = *ip_publica_pc*)(PORT = 1522))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = irm2)
    )
  )

IRM2PDB1 =
  (ADDRESS =
    (PROTOCOL = TCP)
    (HOST = *ip_publica_pc*)
    (PORT = 1522)
  )
```

where ip_publica_pc = public ip and  nombre_de_pc= pc name.  irm2pdb1 is the container name.
Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. I'm feeling completely lost at this point and could use any help to further investigate the issue.

I've already set the environment variables, allowed port access through firewall, and restarted the database and listener.

Comment: that is a really bad idea, you will get problems, such instances belong in a DMZ, if ever and without vital data, if you need access to the database make a ssh tunnel

Comment: Agree with nbk: a database server should never, *never*, ***never*** be on the public Internet. You cannot ask for a faster way to have your data compromised or stolen. A web application server belongs in a DMZ behind a firewall or load balancer, accessing a database on a private network through another firewall with a point-to-point access (think zero trust, app server to db server only). External users should never connect directly to the database, or if *really* necessary should only do so through an SSH tunnel to a bastion host, also in the DMZ.

Comment: Ok thanks for your insights, i'll look into it.